# Flutter - Can I make my MaterialStateProperty<Color> alternate between colors on a loop?

Tags: flutter, material-ui

So I've written a function here to return a material state property, which I'm using to plug into the overlayColor of my ThemeData widget for my various types of buttons.

What it does is shows one color on hover/focus, and returns another color on click, which is pretty nice.

```
MaterialStateProperty<Color> tyButtonOverlay(Color initColor) {
  return MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith((Set<MaterialState> state) {
    if (state.contains(MaterialState.pressed) ||
        state.contains(MaterialState.selected)) {
      return const Color.fromRGBO(7, 214, 105, 0.75);
    } else if (state.contains(MaterialState.focused) ||
        state.contains(MaterialState.hovered)) {
      return const Color.fromRGBO(251, 80, 201, 0.5);
    } else {
      return initColor;
    }
  });
}
```

But I was curious if I could change the return for the focus/hover conditional to return two different colors, and alternate between them. So while you hover over the button it would start (for example) blue and fade to white and come back to blue.

My only idea was to turn it into an async function and add some delays that would switch them back and forth but if I return a future it can't plug into the themedata widget correctly, so that didn't work.